# Internal Server Error after Craft update through admin

Tags: updating

Anyone ever experience getting this after an update through the admin?

`Internal Server Error
mb_strpos(): empty delimiter`

And know of a solution?

Comment: Can you enable devMode, then share the full stack trace leading up to that error?

Comment: Here's a link to a PDF (print) of the stack trace (pretty huge amount of errors). https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/579722/PHP%20warning.pdf

Comment: HTML version of the stack trace; https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/579722/PHP_warning.html

Comment: Look like it might be a Craft bug. Can you send an email to support@craftcms.com referencing this SE post along with a screenshot of how your Craft folder structure is setup on your file system (i.e. where your public html folder is and where the `craft` folder is in related to that.